# CSS Stretched Background Image

Tags: css

I have a large image to be use as a `background-image` of a page. What I want is that the height of the image will be stretched to fill the height of the page. It should be centered also.

```
background: black url("/image/background.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`background-size: cover` will do the trick in modern browsers - see mozilla's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) for more details.

For older browsers (particularly older versions of IE), I've had a lot of success with jQuery plugins like [this one](http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/) to emulate the behaviour.

Comment: this fixed it: `background-size: 1024px 100%;`

Comment: Glad to be able to point you in the direction of what you needed :)

Comment: i couldn't seem to get it working with the `background` tag, but `background-size: cover` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4):

here is a good writeup

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

the gist of it being

```
body { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to the css

```
{
background: black url("/image/background.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
height: 100%;
width:100%
}
```

Comment: Kelvin's answer is perfect if the image is actually larger then the space you want to put it in and will crop it ,  setting width and height will stretch the image

Answer (score 0):

I think using a div would be the easiest way to get the effect you are looking for.

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="/image/background.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
</div>
    <style>
    #background {
        background-color:#000000;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        position: fixed; 
        left: 0px; 
        top: 0px; 
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .stretch {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    </style>
```